# Handling firestore tasks with Promises

Tags: javascript, html, collections, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Promises for Firestore. I have to run this task:

```
db.collection("users").doc(user_uid).collection("grades").doc("g").collection("es111").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
              db.collection("users").doc(user_uid).collection("grades").doc("g").collection("es111").doc(doc.id).delete();
            });
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
          });
```

Here is the first Problem. This task should notice me when its finished. So only if al documents in the collection are deleted. I try to handle this with a promise. I am not sure maybe there are other ways. Thanks in advance.

~filip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to return a `Promise` when all `delete()` actions have completed that you can use with `then()`/`catch()` to perform an action or handle errors. As [delete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#delete) returns `Promise<void>` we can push each delete action to an array of promises that we can use with `Promise.all()`:

```
function foo(user_uid) {
  return db.collection("users").doc(user_uid).collection("grades").doc("g").collection("es111").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    let promises = [];

    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      // add each delete() promise to promises array
      promises.push(db.collection("users").doc(user_uid).collection("grades").doc("g").collection("es111").doc(doc.id).delete());
      // or more simply
      // promises.push(doc.ref.delete());
    });

    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
  });
}

// ...

// usage
foo()
  .then(() => console.log('Success!'))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Another option to consider is using [batched writes](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/transactions):

```
db.collection("users").doc(user_uid).collection("grades").doc("g").collection("es111").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    const batch = db.batch();

    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      batch.delete(doc.ref);
    });

    return batch.commit();
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Batched delete completed!'));
```

It looks like batched writes support a maximum of 500 operations at at time. Notice that you can simply the delete by using [DocumentSnapshot.ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.html#ref) to reference the individual document instead of re-writing the query.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` is the replacement for `.forEach` and `push` combo.

Comment: @AZ_ That will not work with [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) by default as it is not technically an array and does not have operations such as `map()` on it.

Comment: oh didn't know that, Thanks.

Comment: When you say "collection does not exit", do you mean the outer get query? `get()` does return a promise. Do you mean inside the outer `then()` checking if there are no documents? Maybe you can update your question to reflect what you are trying to do for further assistance?